# Why does \zifrefundefined fail on tcolorbox reference?

Tags: tcolorbox, zref

Given this MWE

```latex
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  parskip=half
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{zref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  category=float,
  float,% declares floating environment eq
  floatpos=ht,
  nonfloat,% declares non-floating environment eq-
  listname={Some Items},
  name=TM,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylevel:=table,
  tocentryindent:=table,
  tocentrynumwidth:=table,
  type=MySpecialEnvFloat,
]{ltm}

\newtcolorbox[
    auto counter,
    crefname={TM}{TMs}]{MyBox}[2][]{
    title={TM\,\thetcbcounter: #2},
    #1}

    
\begin{document}

\newcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MySpecialEnv}[4]{%
    \refstepcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}%

    \begin{MyBox}[label={#1}]{#2}
        \addcontentsline{ltm}{section}{TM\,\theMySpecialEnvCounter: #2}
        Some text
        \tcblower
        #4
    \end{MyBox}
}%  

\listofMySpecialEnvFloats

\MySpecialEnv{test-id}{Something that looks like a summary}{-}{
    sdjoajhsja sijaoihs siahskah
}

\MySpecialEnv{test-id-2}{Yet another summary}{-}{
    asjajsaj sakjskaj sjkajs
}

\subsection{varioref test}

Varioref test: Reference to \vref{test-id} and \vref{test-id-2}

Pageref test: \vpageref{test-id-2}

\subsection{Cref Test}

\cref{test-id}  \cpageref{test-id}

\subsection{zifrefundefined}

\zifrefundefined{test-id}{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}{GOOD}

\end{document}
```

I yield

[image: an erroneous result]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Because `tcolorbox` `label` option sets a `\label` and `zref` needs a `\zlabel`. You can load `zref` with `user` option and set if in your environment after `\refstepcounter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zref` uses a separate referencing system from the standard one, so you cannot set a `\label` (which is what the `label=` option of your `tcolorbox` does) and expect for `zref` to find it. However, since the systems are independent, you can have a `zref` label with the same name, which you can create using `\zlabel`, provided by `zref`'s `user` module.

```tex
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  parskip=half
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  category=float,
  float,% declares floating environment eq
  floatpos=ht,
  nonfloat,% declares non-floating environment eq-
  listname={Some Items},
  name=TM,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylevel:=table,
  tocentryindent:=table,
  tocentrynumwidth:=table,
  type=MySpecialEnvFloat,
]{ltm}

\newtcolorbox[
    auto counter,
    crefname={TM}{TMs}]{MyBox}[2][]{
    title={TM\,\thetcbcounter: #2},
    #1}


\begin{document}

\newcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MySpecialEnv}[4]{%
    \refstepcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}%
    \begin{MyBox}[label={#1}]{#2}
        \zlabel{#1}
        \addcontentsline{ltm}{section}{TM\,\theMySpecialEnvCounter: #2}
        Some text
        \tcblower
        #4
    \end{MyBox}
}%

\listofMySpecialEnvFloats

\MySpecialEnv{test-id}{Something that looks like a summary}{-}{
    sdjoajhsja sijaoihs siahskah
}

\MySpecialEnv{test-id-2}{Yet another summary}{-}{
    asjajsaj sakjskaj sjkajs
}

\subsection{varioref test}

Varioref test: Reference to \vref{test-id} and \vref{test-id-2}

Pageref test: \vpageref{test-id-2}

\subsection{Cref Test}

\cref{test-id}  \cpageref{test-id}

\subsection{zifrefundefined}

\zifrefundefined{test-id}{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}{GOOD}

\zref{test-id}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Answers the question as asked. But I have a problem with user-defined values, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633679/nameuse-fails-on-definition-within-tcolorbox for more details.

Comment: @MarkusW. Indeed, that's all I can do. And you already received a good answer there.

Comment: I was not aware about `zlabel`triggerng this. I wanted to define vars an refer to the in the `GOOD` section

Comment: @MarkusW. I don't understand what you think `\zlabel` is "triggering", it just sets a label for `zref`, just like a `\label` does for the standard referencing system.

Comment: The point I want to make is that I need to use `\zref@setcurrent` and that is obviously insufficent as demonstrated in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633679/nameuse-fails-on-definition-within-tcolorbox. So you solved/answered the (bad formulated) question in a surprising way that does not help with `\zref@setcurrent`

Comment: Sorry, I finally get the meaning of "`zref` uses a separate referencing system". See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633756/144487 for what I wanted to achieve